# Как добавить плейлист в музыкальный плеер на Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mediaplayer

Делаю плеер на андроид в качестве своего первого приложения. Нужно добавить плейлист с помощью которого будет производится выбор песни. То есть будет иконка папки, при нажатии на которую появится список на весь экран из треков, которые находятся на sd карте. Иконка папки должна находится на главном экране приложения

Что должно быть:

-Треки в этой папке могут меняться, то есть я могу с компа добавить или удалить треки. Папка должна при открытии показать находящиеся внутри неё треки. А также другие папки, в которых тоже находятся другие треки, можно назвать это альбомами. То есть при открытии этой папки, все вложенные в неё другие папки должны быть видны

-При клике на название трека, он запускается и происходит переход в Main_Activity

Как это реализовать?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/album_art"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_play"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
        android:background="@drawable/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_pause"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_play"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="43dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pause" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_stop"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_play"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="43dp"
        android:background="@drawable/stop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main_Activity.class:

```
package com.kentforth.musicplayer;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button play,pause,stop;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int pauseCurrentPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
        pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);

        play.setOnClickListener(this);
        pause.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch(view.getId()) {

            case R.id.btn_play:
                if(mediaPlayer == null) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.city);
                mediaPlayer.start();}

                else if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(pauseCurrentPosition);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.btn_pause:
                if (mediaPlayer !=null ) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    pauseCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.btn_stop:
                if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer = null;
                }

                break;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Кто делает плеер, мы или вы? Если есть конкретная проблема, то задавайте по ней вопрос. А пока что вы просите написать плеер вместо вас. Здесь этим не занимаются.

Comment: Так в этом и проблема, я не знаю как создается плэйлист. Или как начинающий Андроид разработчик должен узнавать такие вещи?

Comment: Вот, уже лучше. Вместо "как это реализовать" имеем на самом более узкий вопрос - как создается плейлист. Но и этот вопрос очень широкий. Почитайте рубрику "[Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)". Плохой вопрос: "как создается плейлист?" (да как хочется, так и создается, стопицот способов). Хороший вопрос: "я нажимаю кнопку "+", а трек не добавляется в плейлист. Вот код, где тут ошибка?" PS. Начинающие, и не только начинающие разработчики, очень многое узнают из чтения документации, мануалов и прочих руководств.

Comment: И на этом хоть спасибо!